# Specify the ratio of axis precisely

Tags: plotting

When I want to have equal length of the units on both x and y axis, I can use `AspectRatio -> Automatic`. But when I need the unit of x axis have length twice than the length of the unit of y axis, what is the option for this purpose?

Comment: ?AspectRatio
AspectRatio is an option for Graphics and related functions that specifies the ratio of height to width for a plot.  >>

Comment: See this Q&A [How to set the ratio between the vertical and horizontal scales of plots?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/how-to-set-the-ratio-between-the-vertical-and-horizontal-scales-of-plots)

Answer (score 1):

You can fiddle around with PlotRange and AspectRatio:

```
Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -π, π}, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/k], {k, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -π, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/k], {k, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/k], {k, 0.5, 3}]
```

[image]