# How to Set the Ratio of Units of the Axes in a 2D Plot?

Tags: plotting, options

Consider the following plot

```
Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

It is evident that $1$ unit on the $y$ axis is not as the same length of $1$ unit on the $x$ axis. I want the ratio of these units to be one or any other desired value $r=\dfrac{y \,\, \text{axis unit}}{x \,\, \text{axis unit}}$.

I searched for how to determine the scaling of these units of the axes. I encountered [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67147/specify-the-ratio-of-axis-precisely) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/how-to-set-the-ratio-between-the-vertical-and-horizontal-scales-of-plots). But I could not find a nice answer explaining a simple way to do the job. Also, I couldn't find a nice example in the documentation. I just learned from documentation that

> `AspectRatio` determines the ratio of `PlotRange`, not `ImageSize`.

So here is my question

**What is a simple way to manually edit the ratio of the units of the axes?**.

Comment: Check `AspectRatio` option of various plotting functions...

Comment: @unlikely: I read those parts. :) I am afraid that this is not a solution or the explanation in the documentation is not enough! :)

Comment: Try option `Plot[..., AspectRatio->Automatic]`

Comment: @unlikely: Can you kindly write an answer with proper details. I have tried these things already and do not understand what is happening! Sorry but I am a beginner! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get 1:1 unit ratio you can use

```
Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

To get for example 1:2 unit ratio you can use:

```
Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 AspectRatio -> 2*(1.05 + 1.05)/(2 Pi - 0)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As stated by @Sjoerd to define `AspectRatio` properly you should take into account the `PlotRange` as I did.

If you don't know in advance the `PlotRange` of your plot you can also use the following to get it after making an "hidden" plot:

```
g = Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi},
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
   ];
Show[g, AspectRatio -> 2 / Divide @@ (Subtract @@@ PlotRange[g])]
```

Comment: This was the simple answer I was looking for! :) So the key sentence of documentation is `AspectRatio` determines the ratio of `PlotRange`, not `ImageSize`.

Comment: Thanks again. The last solution is interesting. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
pl = Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Determine the actual setting of the `AspectRatio` option used for this plot with `AbsoluteOptions`:

```
ar = AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[pl, AspectRatio]
(* 0.618034 *)
```

The replacement (`/.`) takes care of converting the option rule to an actual number.

With the setting `AspectRation->Automatic` Mathematica scales this such that the units have a ratio of 1 when measured in figure dimensions:

```
plAutomatic = 
 Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The aspect ratio used in this case is:

```
arAutomatic = 
 AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[plAutomatic, AspectRatio]
(* 0.334225 *)
```

Plotting the plot with this value yields the same plot as with `Automatic':

```
Show[pl, AspectRatio -> aut]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we have a value that we can scale. Here by a factor of 2:

```
Show[pl, AspectRatio -> 2 aut]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @H.R. I removed my comments. For 3D: `BoxRatios`