# How can I get a contour plot with isometric scaling?

Tags: plotting, scaling

```
ContourPlot[x^2 == 0.5 (y - 1) y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AspectRatio -> 1/3]
```

Mathematica 12 always gives me an unproportial image!
The aspect ratio option does not work or works in a way I cannot understand.

[image: image by default]

The first image uses the default aspect ratio.

[image: AspectRatio 1:3]

The second one has aspect ratio 1:3, but the x and y unit intervals are still different! They are 41:55. (You can see I drew the red box on the plot wrong and I don't understand why. It should be a perfect square and it really is if borders pass through 1 along x and 2 along y.)

How do I get a plot with equal scales by x an y? (Sorry I've got it already, the question is just a mistake)

Comment: Have you tried AspectRatio->Automatic?

Comment: `AspectRatio` gives the ratio of the final image shape!

Comment: You own this question, so you delete it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111209/how-to-set-the-ratio-of-units-of-the-axes-in-a-2d-plot?rq=1). Apparently we have to take account the plot range when trying to set our aspect ratio:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 == 0.5 (y - 1) y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
 Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y},
PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {1, 3}}, AspectRatio -> (1/3)*(2)/(6)]
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Option `AspectRatio->1/3` is what you are looking for:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 == 0.5 (y - 1) y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y},AspectRatio -> 1/3]
```

[image]

I don't understand why your second image  differs!