# How to align coordinate systems of Inset and enclosing Graphics?

Tags: graphics, alignment, scaling

Suppose we have some plot with `AspectRatio` not being `Automatic`:

```
iIS = 350;
iPR = {{0, 25}, {0, 100}};
iIP = {{20, 5}, {15, 5}};
inset = ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], ImageSize -> iIS, PlotRange -> iPR, 
  AxesStyle -> Bold, ImagePadding -> iIP, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: inset]

Now we wish to place it as `Inset` inside of a larger `Graphics` object (with `Frame->True`) in such a way that the coordinate systems of both plots exactly coincide with each other and the original plot will not be cropped.

What is the right way to align coordinate systems of `Inset` and enclosing `Graphics` exactly?

**The ideal solution would allow setting arbitrary `PlotRange`, `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` for the enclosing `Graphics`.**

---

(This quesiton is a more demanding variation of [How to make Inset graphics maintain relative sizes when combined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/).)

Comment: Is this the same topic or are there any subtleties? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/5478

Comment: @Kuba Yes, [that thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/5478) is related but my question is substantially different: 1) the OP of that question was satisfied by approximate solution while I need exact match; 2) I consider more general case where `AspectRation` is not `Automatic` and both the inset and enclosing graphics have non-zero `ImagePadding`.

Comment: I put a link to that question in your own question that it may serve as a starting point or simpler case depending on circumstance of the reader.

Comment: I'm exploring a way to solve this for completely arbitrary graphics and I'm running into a problem that, for instance, resizing your inset does not resize the `ImagePadding` of the inset (valid and expected behavior, but somewhat complicates things). Does your question, nonetheless imply, that we know the padding of the inset anyway? Is it necessarily given as a fixed amount of printer points, or could it be in `Scaled` or `ImageScaled` coordinates? Could it be `Automatic` as well?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Unfortunately `ImagePadding` accepts only explicit values in printer's points or `All`. Life would be much easier if this option would accept scaled specification. I assume that `ImagePadding` for the inset is specified in printer's points and is known.

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the comment section of the OP I assume that the image padding is a constant number of printer points, though it is not necessarily known. I use the rasterize trick to obtain the size of the plotting range in printer points:

```
printerPointsPlotRange = 
    (#[[2]] - #[[1]] &)@
        (Rasterize[Show[#, Epilog ->
            {Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]],
                "Two", "Region"]}], "Regions"][[-1, 2]]) &
```

Similarly, my own implementation of `ImageDimensions`. It gives the size of the rectangle defined by `Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0,0}],ImageScaled[{1,1}]]` in printer points, which does not always match `ImageDimensions` if `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio` lead to conflicting results:

```
realImageDimensions = 
    (#[[2]] - #[[1]] &)@
        (Rasterize[Show[#, Epilog ->
            {Annotation[Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]],
                "Two", "Region"]}], "Regions"][[-1, 2]]) &
```

I implement a modified version of `PlotRange` to account for `PlotRangePadding`.

```
realPlotRange =
    Module[
      {padding = Total /@ (Options[#, PlotRangePadding][[-1, 2]] /. None -> 0), 
       baserange = (#[[2]] - #[[1]] &) /@ PlotRange[#], range},

      range = (baserange + padding) /. 
        {a_ Scaled[b_] :> Scaled[a b], Scaled[a_] + Scaled[b_] :> Scaled[a + b]} /. 
          {a_ + Scaled[b_] :> a/(1 - b)};
      range] &
```

It appears to fail for mixed specifications, such as `{{1,Scaled[.1]},{Scaled[.02],Scaled[.02]}}`. However if the left and right paddings are *both* given either in `Scaled` form or in the coordinates of the plot and the same holds for the top and bottom padding specs, the function works fine.

```
plotRangeRatio = realPlotRange[#1]/realPlotRange[#2] &
```

Setting everything up:

```
SetOptions[Plot, {GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True}]
gr1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-2, 2}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> {600, 400}, 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
gr2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -.5, 4}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
  ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRange -> {{-.5, 4}, {-1, 1}}]
```

And producing the image:

```
Show[gr1, Epilog ->
    Inset[Show[gr2,
      ImageSize -> 
        plotRangeRatio[gr2, gr1] printerPointsPlotRange[gr1] +
        (realImageDimensions[gr2] - printerPointsPlotRange[gr2]), 
      AspectRatio ->
        (Last[#]/First[#] &)@
          (plotRangeRatio[gr2, gr1] printerPointsPlotRange[gr1])],
     {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]]
```

[image: Plot in plot]

The main assumption here is that the image padding is fixed and does not change upon resizing the image. It should then be always equal to

```
 (realImageDimensions[gr2] - printerPointsPlotRange[gr2])
```

where I do not even care, how wide the padding is on which side, all I care is how much bigger the image is, compared to the size of the plot range. So for plots with `ImagePadding` of `30`, or `{{5,55},{20,40}}` or `{{35,25},{50,10}}` the above code will in all cases return `{60,60}`.

Upon aligning the coordinates the aspect ratio of the graphic being enclosed may change depending on the coordinate scales of the enclosing graphic. It is thus calculated beforehand and set to the appropriate value.

Comment: I appreciate this solution very much, it is great! Your `realPlotRange` currently fails in some cases, you may easily implement more universal analog on the base of my [`completePlotRange` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280) instead. But I appreciate your straightforward approach in the `realPlotRange` implementation.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Please do elaborate, in which cases `realPlotRange` fails, I'd like to explore alternatives.

Comment: For example it fails for `Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]`, it also fails for any graphics for which the function `PlotRange` fails, for example: `Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[1]]},
  Frame -> True]`.

Comment: You can shorten the implementation of `realPlotRange` through an undocumented function: ``realPlotRange[gr_] := #2 - #1 & @@@ Charting`get2DPlotRange[gr]``

Comment: @J.M. ``Charting`get2DPlotRange`` is more advanced currently (v. 10.4.1) than [it was in version 8](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions/18040#comment120604_40237) but it is still Kernel-based and so will fail in many cases including the second example from my [previous comment here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83636/how-to-align-coordinate-systems-of-inset-and-enclosing-graphics#comment226412_83659). It also seemingly gives slightly wrong value for the first example from that comment.

Comment: A nice extension of this answer would be to enable the alignment of an inset that has been rotated to vertical by `Inset[gr,pos,al,dim,{0,-1}]` or `...{0,1}]`.

Answer (score 11):

My way of thinking so far:

1. According to the Documentation, when the third argument of `Inset` is `Automatic`, the inset will have its original size inside of enclosing graphics. Its a good start.
2. The `inset` has non-zero `ImagePadding` (needed for the frame ticks), so some additional space must be added inside of the plot range of the enclosing graphics via `PlotRangePadding`. Probably `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]` is a good value to start with.
3. The enclosing graphics must have larger `ImageSize`. With `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]` the plot range covers a fraction `1-2*0.1` = `0.8` of the whole horizontal plotting range. So the image size must be `iIS/0.8` (where `iIS` is `ImageSize` of the `inset`): `ImageSize -> iIS/.8`.
4. When we increase overall image size we must scale `ImagePadding` proportionally in order to keep original scales for the axes. So we must set `ImagePadding -> iIP/.8`.

What we get with these settings:

```
gr = Graphics[{Inset[
    Show[inset, GridLines -> Automatic], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> iPR, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  ImageSize -> iIS/.8, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> iIP/.8, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]
```

> [image: gr]

This method works but requires a lot of manual tuning of options. I am still looking for a better alternative.

---

### UPDATE 1: `ImageScaled` as fourth argument of `Inset` allows `ImageSize` to be arbitrary

Instead of adjusting `ImageSize` of enclosing graphics it is better to specify the size of the inset in scaled coordinates relative to the size of the enclosing graphics. Then the latter becomes arbitrary. As it is mentioned in p.3 above, the inset will have size `0.8` of the size of the enclosing graphics when `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]`, so the third argument of `Inset` must be `ImageScaled[.8]`:

```
gr2 = Graphics[{Inset[
    Show[inset, GridLines -> Automatic], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
    ImageScaled[.8]]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> iPR, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> iIP/.8, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]
```

> [image: gr2]

With this modification of the original approach we still must fix `AspectRatio`, `PlotRange` and `ImagePadding` of the enclosing graphics but now `ImageSize` is arbitrary! **I'm still loooking for a way to make at least `PlotRange` of the enclosing graphics arbitrary too.**

---

### UPDATE 2: `ImagePadding` "features" and a way to arbitrary `PlotRange`

Further experimentation showed that **`ImagePadding` of the `Inset` isn't scaled by the fourth argument of `Inset` but is applied unscaled**. This can be proven as follows:

```
iIS = 350;
iPR = {{0, 100}, {0, 100}};
iIP = {{20, 5}, {15, 5}};
inset = ListPlot[Range[100], ImageSize -> iIS, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 90}, {0, 90}}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 5 + 25.5}, {15, 5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];
gr3 = Graphics[{Inset[Show[inset, GridLines -> Automatic], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
    ImageScaled[.8]]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> iPR, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> iIP/.8, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], ImageSize -> iIS]
```

> [image: output]

In the above I have reduced the `PlotRange` of the inset by 10%. Correspondingly I must increase `ImagePadding` of the inset in order to keep the scale of the intrinsic coordinate system the same. The perfect match is achieved when I add `25.5` to the horizontal padding. This is calculated as follows:

```
0.1*(0.8*350 - 25)
```

> ```
> 25.5
> ```

where `0.8` is from `ImageScaled[.8]` (the fourth argument of `Inset`), `350` - horizontal `ImageSize` of the inset, `25 = 20 + 5` - horizontal `ImagePadding`, and `0.1` - 10% shortening of the horizontal `PlotRange`. In the above formula horizontal `ImagePadding` isn't multiplied by `0.8` (as one could expect) because scaling isn't applied to `ImagePadding`.

**This feature is very unfortunate** because it makes the plot not scalable again: for keeping the perfect match we must fix `ImageSize` of the enclosing graphics. But knowing this feature, we now [can make](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119538/280) `PlotRange` of the inset arbitrary!

One should also take into account that when the `ImageSize -> w` specification is used, the vertical `ImagePadding` seems to be ignored!

Comment: Alexey, if you don't mind my asking, what is the point you are trying to achieve? I can't think of a reason one would want to have an inset that takes most of the space in the surrounding plot, so I am having a hard time thinking of solutions. Could you tell us a bit more about what you would like to do with it?

Comment: This approach can have interesting applications in infographics but original motivation was much more utilitarian: currently in *Mathematica* we have no direct way to control the distance between tick labels and frame and it came to mind that one possible way is to create an `Inset` only with frame and place it inside of another graphics which has only tick labels. But actually I already have used it in situations where I need to have two coordinate systems at the same time on the plot exactly aligned with each other.

Comment: Cool! Thank you, I was sure that I was missing something here, and I was quite curious to see where this was going. Thank you for commenting on this!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that allows dynamic resizing of the image with a mouse.

As shown by @LLlAMnYP, in order to get [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) graphics to line up with the coordinate system of the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object, it is necessary to know both the absolute [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) and [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) of the inset graphics, as well as the absolute [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) and [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) of the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html). This is because the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) and the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) of a graphic are independently controllable. Consider the following diagram:

[image]

To line up with the coordinate system of the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object, the ratio of the plot range point sizes of the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) object and the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object must be the same as the ratio of their absolute plot ranges. The total inset size will then be the plot range point size plus the image padding. Consider the horizontal dimension. If we set:

- ratio =  ratio of absolute plot ranges of the inset and enclosing graphics
- inset =  total image padding (left + right) of the inset object
- size  =  plot range point size of the enclosing graphics object

Then the horizontal size of the inset (in points) should be:

```
ratio * size + inset
```

or in [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates:

```
Scaled[ratio + inset / size]
```

Notice that for nonzero inset, both of these expressions (and the equivalent [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html) version) depend on the size of the [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html). This means that the size of the inset must change in a nontrivial way when the size of the enclosing graphics object is modified (e.g. by using the mouse). Therefore, to obtain a graphic where the inset graphics remain aligned to the enclosing graphic when the size is modified, one needs to use [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html).

All that remains is to determine the necessary graphics information for the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) and enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) objects. This can be done by using the `graphicsInformation` function from my answer to question [2091](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431). Using this function, we can construct a dynamically updated graphics object where [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) objects are aligned correctly inside of an enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object even when the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object is resized:

```
Options[overlayGraphics] = Options[Graphics];

overlayGraphics[prim_:{}, g:{__Graphics}, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
    {insetInfo, insetRanges, graphRange, graphInfo},

    insetInfo = graphicsInformation /@ g;

    insetRanges = "PlotRange" /. insetInfo;
    graphRange = Replace[OptionValue[PlotRange],
        Except[{{_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ},{_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ}}] :> combinedRange[insetRanges]
    ];
    graphInfo = graphicsInformation @ Graphics[prim, PlotRange -> graphRange, opts];
    graphRange = "PlotRange" /. graphInfo;

    With[
        {
        graphImagePadding = "ImagePadding" /. graphInfo,
        graphImagePaddingSize = "ImagePaddingSize" /. graphInfo,
        insetPadding = "ImagePadding" /. insetInfo,
        ratios = ScalingTransform[1/xyRange[graphRange]][xyRange/@insetRanges]
        },

        DynamicModule[{w,h},
            With[
                {
                insets = MapThread[
                    toInset[##, {w,h} - graphImagePaddingSize]&,
                    {g, insetPadding, insetRanges, ratios}
                ]
                },

                {w,h} = "ImageSize" /. graphInfo;
                Graphics[
                    {
                    prim,
                    insets
                    },

                    PlotRange -> graphRange, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
                    AspectRatio -> Full, ImagePadding -> graphImagePadding,
                    ImageSize -> Dynamic[{w,h}], opts
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

combinedRange[p_] := MinMax /@ Transpose[p]

xyRange[{{a_,b_}, {c_,d_}}] := {b-a, d-c}

toInset[
    gr_Graphics,
    pad:{{l_, r_}, {b_, t_}},
    pr_,
    {xratio_, yratio_},
    {width_, height_}
] := Inset[
    Show[gr, PlotRange->pr, PlotRangePadding->0, AspectRatio->Full, ImagePadding->pad],
    {0,0},
    {0,0},
    Dynamic @ Scaled[{xratio + (r+l)/width, yratio + (b+t)/height}]
]
```

Some implementation details.

1. I insert the explicit absolute plot range (with [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html)->0) and image padding into the inset and enclosing graphics so that any [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) adjustments to [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) and [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) are avoided.
2. I use [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html)->[`Full`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Full.html) for the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) objects so that the 4th argument of the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) controls the full size of the inset.
3. I use [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html)->[`Full`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Full.html) and explicit `w` and `h` [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) values for the enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object so that the resizing boxes directly control the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html).

Here is `overlayGraphics` applied to your example `inset`:

```
overlayGraphics[
    {},
    {
    Show[inset, GridLines->Automatic]
    },
    Frame->True, FrameStyle->Red, PlotRange->{{-5, 35}, {-10, 110}},
    ImageSize->500, AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio, GridLines->Automatic
]
```

[image]

Here is another example:

```
overlayGraphics[
    {Red, Line[{{-1,-1.5}, {0,0}}]},
    {
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}],
    Graphics[{Circle[{-1, -1.5}, .5]}, ImagePadding->{{1, 2}, {3.3, 4.4}}]
    },
    AspectRatio -> .5, ImageSize -> 600, GridLines->Automatic, ImagePadding->20
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very slick!  Happy to be the first to upvote this. :-)