# AspectRatio option works unpredictably?

Tags: graphics, options

Let us examine the agreement between specified value for the `AspectRatio` option and the actual aspect ratio of generated plot. For this purpose I define a function which uses the [`Rasterize` trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83659/280) for determination of the actual aspect ratio:

```
realAspectRatio = #2/#1 & @@ (#2 - #1) & @@ 
    Rasterize[
      Show[#, Epilog -> {Annotation[
          Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]], "Two", 
          "Region"]}], "Regions"][[-1, 2]] &;
```

(Instead of `realAspectRatio@` one can use much more basic but lesser precise function `#2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions@` what gives the same results.)

At first, we check the agreement for simple graphics `Graphics[{Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]`:

```
table = Table[{10^p, realAspectRatio@
     Graphics[{Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, AspectRatio -> 10^p]}, {p, -2, 2, .1}];
lm = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
lm["BestFit"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {"AspectRatio", "fit residual"}]
```

> 1.26421 + 0.603143 x
>
> [image: plot]

One can see that actual aspect ratio substantially differs from the requested via the `AspectRatio` option and the dependence between them is nonlinear!

In this case the situation becomes MUCH better if we provide at least horizontal `PlotRange` specification `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}`:

```
table = Table[{10^p, 
    realAspectRatio@
     Graphics[{Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 10}}]}, AspectRatio -> 10^p, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}]}, {p, -2, 2, .1}];
lm = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
lm["BestFit"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"AspectRatio", "fit residual"}]
```

> 0.00391481 + 1.00225 x
>
> [image: plot]

But for a little more complex graphics `ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]]` this remedy does not help even if we vary `AspectRatio` in much lesser diapason from 1/5 to 5:

```
table = Table[{ar, realAspectRatio@
      ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 100}}, 
       AspectRatio -> ar]}, {ar, 1/5, 5, .1}];
lm = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
lm["BestFit"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"AspectRatio", "fit residual"}]
```

> 0.248369 + 0.768459 x
>
> [image: plot]

How this behavior can be explained? Is it intended behavior?
And more importantly: **is there a way to make the actual aspect ratio predictable?**

---

### Summary of the discussion and the conclusion

The source of confusion was the first sentence under the "Details" section on [the Documentation page for `AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html): "`AspectRatio` determines the scaling for the final image shape." This statement is clearly wrong and more correct statement can be found as the first point under the "Properties and Relations" subsection in the "Examples" section on the same page: "`AspectRatio` determines the ratio of `PlotRange`, not `ImageSize`." But as it is clearly demonstrated [in dedicated answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83810/280), even this statement is not precise because actually **`AspectRatio` determines the aspect ratio of the plotting area which is specified by both `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`**.

Comment: In 10.1 it seems that neither `Scaled` not `ImageScaled` correctly place a `Rectangle` aligned with the range of the plot therefore any calculations based on these are inaccurate.  *Edit:* I forgot about `PlotRangePadding`.  With that set to zero the rectangle aligns.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard With `#2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions@` instead of `realAspectRatio@` I get roughly  the same picture. I'm surprised that `ImageScaled` works incorrectly because my little experimentation with plots in the question showed correct behavior of `realAspectRatio`.

Comment: Alexey, Have you tried removing any ImagePadding from your graphic?

Comment: @MarcoB We seem to be thinking alike.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that there is little point in making the image size so small that the image cannot possibly have a close to accurate aspect ratio.  If I also get rid of the superfluous parts outside of the plot range by setting `PlotRangePadding`, `ImagePadding`, and `ImageMargins` all to zero, I can use simple `ImageDimensions` to check aspect ratio.  Doing all this I find that it is quite precise in 10.1 under Windows:

```
table = Table[{10^p, 
    N[#2/#] & @@ 
     ImageDimensions@
      Image@Graphics[{Disk[]}, AspectRatio -> 10^p, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
        ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {2000}]}, {p, -2, 2, .1}];

lm = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
lm["BestFit"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"AspectRatio", "fit residual"},
  DataRange -> {10^-2, 10^2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
> -0.00279057 + 1.00046 x
> ```

[image]

Likewise your `ListPlot` example:

```
table = Table[{ar, 
    N[#2/#] & @@ 
     ImageDimensions@
      Image@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 100}}, 
        AspectRatio -> ar, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
        ImageSize -> {2000}]}, {ar, 1/5, 5, .1}];

lm = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
lm["BestFit"]
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"AspectRatio", "fit residual"},
 DataRange -> {1/5, 5}]
```

> ```
> 0.000344083 + 0.999798 x
> ```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking as well. I had tried simply adding `ImagePadding -> None` to the `Graphics` in @AlexeyPopov's question, and the fit returns a coefficient of $1$, with fit residuals within a MachineEpsilon of zero. You have a good point about not making the image too small to be sensible though.

Comment: Now I see the problem: `ImagePadding` is ignored when the final aspect ratio is calculated and is added AFTER the calculation. It is very unexpected discovery for me.

Comment: @Alexey Why would that be unexpected?  Surely the aspect ratio of the plotted data itself is most important?

Comment: You are right, the aspect ratio of the plot range is the most important thing. But according to the Documentation `AspectRatio` is about overall image size, not just about the plot range!

Comment: @Alexey I don't know if I interpret the documentation that way.  Do you have a specific section in mind? Ah, OK.  I still think that is rather ambiguous, but that's a fault of the documentation writers not you for interpreting it.

Comment: See the first line in the Details section on the Documentation page for `AspectRatio`: "`AspectRatio` determines the scaling for the final image shape." I do not think that the end of this sentence can be interpreted as "the final plotting range shape."

Comment: @Alexey You certainly have a point, yet it wouldn't make sense for `AspectRatio` to work that way; if it did when using `Automatic` circles would vary from round with every tick mark and label added to a plot.

Comment: I thought that `Automatic` is an exclusive mode for `AspectRatio`. Are you sure that `AspectRatio -> 1` is equivalent to `AspectRatio -> Automatic`? For which purpose they introduced the `Automatic` setting? If you are right it just misleads a user.

Comment: Did I state that `AspectRatio -> 1` is equivalent to `Automatic`?  I hope not as that would be incorrect.  Automatic scales the graphic such that primitives are non-distorted, i.e. circles are circles.  This isn't the first time the documentation has been unclear or flat out wrong, but I still think this is the logical way for `AspectRatio` to work.  I guess I never read the documentation that carefully; I just experimented and observed.  Actually that's probably how I learned most of what I knew about *Mathematica* before joining Stack Exchange.

Comment: I see that learning by trial and error method is more efficient than mine: I read at least a few first lines in the Documentation and then I proceeded as if these were the true. Now I see that even the first few lines may be false during many versions and (!) for a basic function. It is frustrating for me.

Comment: @Alexey You have my sympathy.  Though I rank discovering that a newly introduced function performs far more poorly than existing alternatives as *more* frustrating. :-p

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov to be fair, the documentation does say that "`AspectRatio` determines the ratio of `PlotRange`, not `ImageSize`" (see the first point under "Properties and Relations"). To me, that *does* seem to describe the observed (and most desirable) behavior. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: @MarcoB I agree. But this statement must be in the "Details" section, not hidden somewhere in the examples.

Comment: @MarcoB After reading of the [dedicated answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83810/280) I realize that even this statement is not completely correct: actually `AspectRatio` determines the ratio of not just `PlotRange` but of the whole plotting are with `PlotRangePadding` included. It seems that many sentences in the Documentation are taken directly from the Documentation for version 5 where we had no such option as `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov regarding the difference between plot range and plot range plus padding, allow me to add to your confusion: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.8, .8}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .3]` note how the curve is clipped beyond `.8`, however the part with `x>2` is plotted, although that is also merely the padding, not the explicitly specified `PlotRange`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I see your example as an indication that `PlotRangePadding` is not completely correctly integrated into `Plot`. But it does not alter my view of the `AspectRatio` behavior expressed in my last comment.