# What does the AspectRatio option actually do?

Tags: graphics, options, documentation, scaling

The Documentation for `AspectRatio` on its first line under the "**Details**" section states: "`AspectRatio` determines the scaling for **the final image shape**" (emphasis is mine). But the practice shows that is it not true: it [seems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83766/aspectratio-option-works-unpredictably#comment226656_83771) that this option affects only aspect ratio of the plot range but not the aspect ratio of the whole image (with `ImagePadding` and `ImageMargings` added). It is a basic graphics option but we still know a little about it...

What the option `AspectRatio` actually do? How it interacts with `PlotRangePadding`, `ImagePadding`, `ImageMargings` and `ImageSize`?

It would be ideal to have a ***mathematical model*** of interaction between these options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AspectRatio option works unpredictably?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83766/aspectratio-option-works-unpredictably)

Comment: @David My intention was to create a summary question where many aspects of working of the `AspectRatio` options would be summarized and cleared out. [That question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83766/aspectratio-option-works-unpredictably) was too highly specialized, this is intended as a clarification of the Documentation for `AspectRatio` which is [misleading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83766/aspectratio-option-works-unpredictably#comment226661_83771).

Comment: It seems to me that a mathematical model would be exceedingly complicated to arrive at in this case. The aspect ratio one calculates from the dimensions of a rasterized output depends on how much space had to be allocated to things like ticks and axes etc. This in turn depends not only on the data to be plotted, but also on adventitious parameters such as font size, tick choice, etc.

Comment: @MarcoB The mathematical model may describe just relationships between numerical values of parameters and do not account for symbolic values (such as `All` etc.). In this case font size, tick choice, etc. does not matter.

Comment: This question has my support.  If I have time it will also have my answer.

Comment: I posted an answer.  I did not attempt a "mathematical model" but I also do not feel that it is necessary unless there are complexities beyond those I illustrate.  Please let me know if you find any.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. I think that one such under-documented point is a situation when `ImageSize` conflicts with the shape which follows from the other options.

Comment: I added a note about `ImageSize` to my answer.  I only explored a single case however; if you find contradictions please let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Padding

Without padding of any kind the over-all aspect ratio and element (primitive) aspect ratio are the same and as specified:

```
g0 =
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5, Red], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]}, AspectRatio -> 2/3, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

(There is a one pixel discrepancy along the right edge where the background shows through but I believe that is within the margin of error for rasterization in *Mathematica*.  That is to say there are other small discrepancies that would also need to be accounted for before considering this a specific aspect ratio problem.)

```
g0 // Image // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {360, 240}
> ```

[`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) is *included* in the aspect ratio calculation such that the extended plot area has the specified aspect ratio which means that elements have a different aspect ratio unless the padding is such that it exactly matches the aspect ratio.

```
g1 =
 Show[g0, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {15, 2}, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

The image dimensions are similar to `g0` though the `Rectangle` is clearly distorted.

```
g1 // Image // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {360, 240}
> ```

If the ratio of the `PlotRangePadding` matches the numeric `AspectRatio` the image aspect ratio and the element aspect ratio match:

```
Show[g0, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {3, 2}, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

[`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) is *excluded* from the calculation of aspect ratio; it is area added outside the plot area but within the graphic area where e.g. `Background` applies and where ticks and labels may reside.  With `PlotRangePadding -> 0` the element aspect ratio is still exactly as specified by `AspectRatio`.

```
g2 = 
  Show[g0, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImagePadding -> {{70, 70}, {20, 8}}, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

```
g2 // Image // ImageDimensions
```

> {360, 175}

[`ImageMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMargins.html) is *excluded* from aspect ratio *and* image size calculations.  It extends the image beyond the specified size with a blank area; it may not contain ticks or labels.

```
g3 =
 Show[g0, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
  ImageMargins -> {{30, 30}, {50, 50}}]
```

[image]

The image is larger than the default width-360:

```
g3 // Image // ImageDimensions
```

> {420, 340}

### ImageSize

When an absolute [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) is given that does not match the requested ratio the graphic is scaled down to fit entirely within that size and the image area is extended to match the absolute size.  The exception is `ImageMargins` (`g3`) which as stated before is excluded from `ImageSize`; it adds padding *outside* of that bounding box.

```
Show[#, ImageSize -> {160, 180}] & /@ {g0, g1, g2, g3}
```

[image]

```
ImageDimensions /@ Image /@ %
```

> ```
> {{160, 180}, {160, 180}, {160, 180}, {220, 280}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

`Scaled` and `ImageScaled` coordinates are extremely useful to study the behaviors of the options for `Graphics`. I'll try to contribute what I can. What follows, mostly applies to `Plot` and similar functions. Often `Graphics` created explicitly with the `Graphics` head, such as those in Mr.Wizard's answer may behave differently, as compared to `Plot`.

First example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1},
     Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> {360, 360},
     ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
     Epilog -> {Opacity[.2], Yellow, 
                Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}],
                          ImageScaled[{1, 1}]
                         ]
               }
    ]
```

> [image: Output]

```
Show[%, AspectRatio -> 2]
```

> [image: Output2]

```
ImageDimensions @ %%
ImageDimensions @ %%
```

> `{360, 360}`
>   `{360, 360}`

Conflicting specifications for `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio` lead to a plot, that is as large as possible, while conforming to `AspectRatio` and not exceeding the `ImageSize`. I find especially peculiar the fact, that `ImageScaled[{0,0}]` is at the boundary of the *padding of the image*, not the lower-left corner of the entire graphic. This is illustrated by the translucent yellow rectangle, which occupies the `ImageScaled` range from `{0,0}` to `{1,1}`, while the light-blue background covers the entire `{360, 360}` square.

As Alexey pointed out, the accurate description of `AspectRatio`'s behavior is hidden quite deep in the documentation, specifically under the "Properties and Relations" tab.

> `AspectRatio` determines the ratio of `PlotRange`, not `ImageSize`.

This is easily tested with the rasterize trick, similar to what Alexey did in the linked question.

```
g = 
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1},
     Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> {360, 360},
     ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
     Epilog -> {Opacity[.2], Yellow, 
                Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}],
                          ImageScaled[{1, 1}]
                         ],
                Green,
                Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}],
                                     Scaled[{1, 1}]
                                    ],
                           "One", "Region"
                          ]
               }
    ]
```

> [image: Scaled]

The green rectangle is annotated and covers the `PlotRange`, *as per definition* of `Scaled`. I use `Rasterize` to get the coordinate range it occupies in terms of printer points:

```
Rasterize[g, "Regions"]
```

> `{{"One", "Region"} -> {{30., 105.}, {330., 255.}}}`

This output means, that the annotated rectangle occupies pixels lying in the range from `{30., 105.}` to `{330., 255.}`. These are `Real` numbers, by the way, not integers. `Rasterize` in this respect is very accurate and can calculate sizes to three digits past the decimal, unlike, say, `ImageDimensions` which returns integers. Also, when using this trick for other needs, it's very important to remember, that the coordinates in the rasterized graphics are flipped. `x` is zero on the left, as usual, but `y=0` is located *at the top of the image*.

```
Table[#2/#1 & @@ (#2 - #1) & @@ 
  Rasterize[Show[g, AspectRatio -> i], "Regions"][[-1, 2]], {i, .1, 1.9, .1}]
```

> `{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... , 1.7, 1.8, 1.9}`

That much we knew. The plot range or, in other words, the `Scaled[{0,0}]` to `Scaled[{1,1}]` ranges conforms to the `AspectRatio`. `Show` is convenient in allowing us to override any of the options of `g`. Therefore we can study effects of altering `PlotRangePadding` and others:

```
Table[#2/#1 & @@ (#2 - #1) & @@ 
  Rasterize[Show[g, AspectRatio -> i,
                    PlotRangePadding -> 1,
                    ImagePadding -> {{150, 6}, {100, 20}}],
            "Regions"][[-1, 2]], {i, .1, 1.9, .1}]
```

However, the output remains the same. This can be easily expanded to a `Dynamic` or `Manipulate` construct, but I feel that *"`AspectRatio` controls the height-to-width of the `PlotRange`"* is a sufficiently exhaustive description. See my edit regarding `PlotRangePadding` and it being or not being a part of `PlotRange`.

**EDIT**

As Alexey rightly points out, in my answer I am dismissing the subtle difference between `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`. `AspectRatio`, as observed, controls the height-to-width of the sum of `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`. Well, allow me to confuse you all further:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.9, .9}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .3, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.2], Yellow, 
   Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]], Green, 
   Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], "One", 
    "Region"]}]
```

> [image: Padding?]

So how would we like to define things? `PlotRangePadding` increases the `PlotRange` and the true-real-full `PlotRange` is that what is specified plus the padding? Then my definition of the behavior of `AspectRatio` is ok. But if we're arguing about definitions... Sin[x] is plotted in the `x>2` range, so I suppose the regions of `-2.3<x<-2 && 2<x<2.3` could be considered part of the plot range which was expanded by the `PlotRangePadding` option. On the other hand, the curve is not plotted in the `-1<y<-.9 && .9<y<1` range, so here `PlotRangePadding` did not expand the `PlotRange`.

Comment: Thank you for another great answer but I cannot agree that the statement that `Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]` covers the `PlotRange` is exhaustive: if you add non-zero `PlotRangePadding` it becomes obvious that `Scaled` covers *also* `PlotRangePadding`. And the exhaustive statement would be that it covers `PlotRange` with `PlotRangePadding` added. Similarly I cannot agree that the statement "`AspectRatio` controls the height-to-width of the `PlotRange`" is exhaustive because it says nothing about `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: Yes, I was reflecting on that just now in a comment on the answer to your previous question.

Comment: In response to the EDIT section: I feel natural to say that `PlotRangePadding` increases the plot range but not the value of the `PlotRange` option which remains the same as can be verified by applying `Options[#, PlotRange]&`. I also have to stress that `Plot` returns an object with `Head` `Graphics`. This object has no "stamp" that it was created by `Plot` and by essence is the same `Graphics` that can be constructed by user in many other ways without the built-in plotting functions.

Comment: Yes, in that sense padding increases the range, and **then** its height-to-width is determined by `AspectRatio`. An example of different behaviors: `g1=Plot[...,PlotRangePadding->Scaled[.1]]; g2=Graphics[{},PlotRangePadding->Scaled[.1]];Options[#,PlotRangePading]&/@{g1,g2}` returns `{{Scaled[.1],Scaled[.1]},{Scaled[.1],Scaled[.1]}}` in the first case and simply `Scaled[.1]` in the second.

Comment: Functions like `Plot` and `ListPlot` usually process their `Graphics`-related options in some way instead of passing them down to the final `Graphics` unchanged. They do so even when it is not needed what sometimes results in unexpected behavior or bugs ([example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47406/280)).

Comment: I have created [dedicated question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1554/280) on Meta.Mathematica.SE about terminology.

Answer (score 6):

A minor addition to the other answers.

As it is recently [uncovered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145446/280) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll), `ImageSize` accepts undocumented form

```
ImageSize -> Automatic -> {width, height}
```

which allows you to specify the width and height of the *plot range* directly.

This option has higher precedence than `AspectRatio`:

```
gr = Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {300, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]]

ImageCrop[%] // ImageDimensions
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> {300, 100}
> ```

It can be used in combination with `AspectRatio`:

```
Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic -> {Automatic, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1/3, Frame -> True, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]]

ImageCrop[%] // ImageDimensions
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> {300, 100}
> ```

The only (but crucial!) drawback is that this undocumented form doesn't play well when `Graphics` is wrapped by `Inset`:

```
Graphics[{Inset[gr, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]}, Background -> LightGreen, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 150}]
```

> [image: output]

A workaround is to wrap `Graphics` by `Pane`, `Framed`, `Text` or `ExpressionCell`:

```
Graphics[{Inset[Text[gr]]}, Background -> LightGreen, AspectRatio -> 1/3]

ImageCrop@ImageCrop@% // ImageDimensions
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> {300, 100}
> ```

Unfortunately with this workaround we loose the ability to position inset relative to the coordinates in the intrinsic coordinate system of its `Graphics` object as well as relative to `Scaled` coordinates inside its *plotting range*. :(

Comment: It is so strange that this `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {width, height}` useful setting is still not documented in 2021 ...