# How to scale multiple graphics to preserve relative sizes?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

I'm looking for a simple way to make the displays of different `Graphics` expressions accurately reflect their relative sizes.

(By "simple" I mean that it does not require me to calculate explicit 
`ImageSize` settings for the various expressions.  IOW, I'm looking for something analogous to `AspectRatio -> Automatic`, which obviates the need to compute the specific values for `AspectRatio` required to make *axes* have the same scaling.)

For example, in the `Graphics` expressions used to generate the display below, the circles have the same radius, but as displayed, the one on the left appears twice as big.  Conversely, the star polygons are displayed as having the same size, but the radius specified for the one on the left is half of the radius for the one on the right.

```
Clear[{star, g}];

star[r_] := 
 Polygon[Table[r {Sin[2 Pi k 3/8], Cos[2 Pi k 3/8]}, {k, 8}]]; 

g[content_] := 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], Opacity[0], content}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0.1],
  ImagePadding -> 30, ImageMargins -> 15, 
  Background -> LightGreen(*, GridLines -> Automatic*)];

Array[g[{star[0.9 #], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}] &, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the problem is complicated by the presence of options such as `ImagePadding`, `ImageMargins`, and `PlotRangePadding`.

EDIT: I commented out `GridLines -> Automatic` in the example above, because the unpredictability of this option's effects makes the problem unnecessarily difficult.

Also, I've added a `PlotRangePadding` setting to the example above, so that it more closely matches the illustration given further below.

Lastly, although the example above does not require explicitly setting `AspectRatio->Automatic`, it's safe to assume that I'm dealing with images for which this condition holds, either by default or via an explicit setting.

---

Just to be clear, below I illustrate what I'm looking for.  The illustration invokes a *hypothetical* `Scaling` option, that one could use to specify the relationship between displayed pixels and "`Graphics`-space coordinates".  E.g. `Scaling -> 48` means "48 pixels per unit in '`Graphics`-space'".

```
{
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
   Opacity[0], {star[0.9], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}}, Frame -> True, 
  Background -> LightGreen, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
  ImagePadding -> 30, ImageMargins -> 15, Scaling -> 48],
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
   Opacity[0], {star[2 0.9], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}}, Frame -> True, 
  Background -> LightGreen, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
  ImagePadding -> 30, ImageMargins -> 15, Scaling -> 48]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, AFAIK, there's no `Scaling` option.  I got the output above by painstakingly calculating the settings for `ImageSize` that would produce the right output.  This case is particularly easy (very symmetrical images,`Scaled` units for `PlotRangePadding`, etc.), but in general it is a bear to compute these `ImageSize` values reliably.  I'm hoping to find a way to get *Mathematica* to do this job, and if there isn't one, then at least find a custom solution that does it reasonably reliably.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83659/280)  shows how to obtain the plot range in printer's points.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem arises from another `Graphics` option,`PlotRange`, having the default value `Automatic`, which gives each `Graphics` object its own plot range. To get what you want you will need to force each `Graphics` object to have the ***same*** plot range. Here is something that works for your example. I have made it a little more general than needed because I think you might need the added generality in your actual situation.

```
star[r_] := Polygon[Table[r {Sin[2 Pi k 3/8], Cos[2 Pi k 3/8]}, {k, 8}]]

g[content_, {px_, py_}] := 
  Graphics[
    {EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], Opacity[0], content},
    PlotRange -> {{-px, px}, {-py, py}},
    Frame -> True,
    ImagePadding -> 30,
    ImageMargins -> 15,
    ImageSize -> Small,
    Background -> LightGreen,
    GridLines -> Automatic]

Row @ Array[g[{star[0.9 #], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}, {-2, 2}] &, 2]
```

[image: stars]

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited my post to specify more precisely what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as I understand it, is to display a graphic with its `ImageSize` proportional to its "real" size.  So, in an ideal world one would use something like

```
plt=Graphics[ ... ];
plt=Show[plt, ImageSize -> AbsoluteOptions[plt, RealSize][[1,2]]/scalefactor]
```

The problems are, there may be no `Option` equivalent to `RealSize` and, if there is, `AbsoluteOptions` might well return `Automatic`.

As an alternative, the following works for plots similar to that in Question.

```
g[content_, isiz_, ipad_] := 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], Opacity[0], content}, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> Scaled[ipad], ImageMargins -> 15, Background -> LightGreen, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Scaled[2 ipad + isiz/6]]; 
Row@Array[g[{star[0.9 #], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}, 0.9 #, .03] &, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the undocumented form `ImageSize -> a -> b`
(which makes *a* user units correspond to *b* printer's points) does exactly what you want from your *Scaling*.

You can use it simply as `ImageSize -> 1 -> 48` in any function that accepts the option `ImageSize`.

Alternatively, you can use it to define your custom option (`$Scaling`) and use as `$Scaling -> 48`.

```
ClearAll[$Scaling]
$Scaling /: Rule[$Scaling, s_] := ImageSize -> 1 -> s
```

***Example:***

```
{g1, g2} =
 {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
   Opacity[0], {star[0.9], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}}, Frame -> True, 
   Background -> LightGreen, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
   ImagePadding -> 30, ImageMargins -> 15, $Scaling -> 48], 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
   Opacity[0], {star[2 0.9], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}}, Frame -> True, 
   Background -> LightGreen, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
   ImagePadding -> 30, ImageMargins -> 15, $Scaling -> 48]}
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{g2, RemoveBackground[g1, {"Background", LightGreen}]}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Replace `$Scaling -> 48` with  `$Scaling -> {48, 96}` to get

[image]

**See also:**

1. [Exporting image and scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125)
2. [Maintaining shape size while rotating in GraphicsGrid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263198/125)
3. [Graphics - nice variant of ImageSize (pixels per GraphicsUnitLength)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286125/125)

Comment: A (+1) just for showing the way to another undocumented functionality. Loved it!!!