# Can you dimension the frame in a plot with absolute unit e.g. cm?

Tags: plotting, frame

Is it possible to set the height and width of a plot in absolute units for in $\rm{cm}$? Ideally I'd specifically like to control the frame size for when the plot option `Frame->True` is set?

I've seen that you can set the size of the export plot in absolute units, but can't uncover anything where I can set the size of the frame and plot region explicitly in a notebook.

Comment: try `cm = 72/2.54 ; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 2 cm]`  ro `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 1 -> {3 cm, cm}]`. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125) to a related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the (still undocumented) form `ImageSize -> a -> b` to make `a` user units correspond to `b` printer's points. (See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125) to a related question.)

```
cm = 72/2.54 ; 

Column[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 2 cm],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True,  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 1 -> {2 cm, cm}] ,
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 1 -> {2 cm, 3 cm}] }]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Why is there so much undocumented stuff in M?!