# Fixing histogram size behavior within grid of graphics

Tags: labeling, charts, histograms, grid-layouts

I'm trying to put the finishing touches on a grid of figures and could use some help.  I'm trying to keep the figures as clean as possible, so I only want frame ticks and labels on the edge figures. However, when I do this, the figures on the far left and right are shrunk relative to the middle ones.  I'd love to know how to fix this.

Here's the code and output.

```
(*set up scaling of population sizes*)
iVals = {1/2, 2, 8, 16};

(*create simulations *)
Table[
  Ne = 8*i;
  initialCount  = Ne; (*allele frequency = initialCount/(2 Ne) *)
  
  tMax = 5;
  nPops = 100;
  
  driftMatrix[i] = 
   Table[
     (*each row is the distribuiton of p at given generation *)
     
     NestList[
        RandomInteger[BinomialDistribution[2 Ne, #/(2 Ne)]] &, 
        initialCount, tMax + 1]/(2 Ne) // N, {i, nPops}] // 
    Transpose,
   {i, iVals}];

(*set up the bins*)
binWidth = {0.05};
binBoundaries = Range[ 0 - binWidth/2, 1 + binWidth/2, binWidth];
bin = binWidth;

(*choose which time steps to plot *)
tSteps = 10;
tVals = Range[0, 5];
rowVals = tVals + 1;

(*make the plots *)
plots = Table[
    Table[
     xTicks = If[j == Max[rowVals], Range[0, 1, 0.25], None];
     lTicks = 
      If[i == Min[iVals], {{10, Style["0.5", Smaller]}} , None];
     rTicks = 
      If[i == Max[iVals], {{10, Style["0.5", Smaller]}} , None];
     rFrame = If[i == Max[iVals], True , False];
     Histogram[
      driftMatrix[i][[j]], binBoundaries, "PDF", 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 12}},
      Frame -> {{True, rFrame}, {True, False}},
      FrameTicks -> { 
        {lTicks, rTicks},
        {xTicks, None }
        },
      AspectRatio -> 1/3
      ], {j, rowVals}], {i, iVals}] // Transpose;

(*combine plots into a Grid*)

xlabels = 
  Text[Style[#, Medium]] & /@ (Join[8*iVals, {"Generation"}]);
ylabels = Text[Style[#, Medium]] & /@ (tVals);
Show[
 Labeled[
  Grid[
   Join[
    {xlabels},
    Transpose[
     Join[Transpose[plots], {ylabels}]
     ]
    ], Spacings -> {1, 0}
   ],
  {"Population Size", "Bin Frequency", 
   "Frequency of bw75 Allele"}, {Top, Left, Bottom},
  RotateLabel -> True],
 ImageSize -> 12*72
 ]
```

[image: Grid of Histograms]

It's subtle, but if you look you'll see that the frame lines of the left and right most plots don't match up with the interior ones.

Comment: try if adding the option  `ImageSize -> 1 -> 160`  to `Histogram` gives what you need.

Comment: try also [Lukas Lang's PlotGrid](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid)

Comment: @kglr Thanks for both suggestions.   The first works almost perfectly, but there's actually an extremely slight difference in the length of the x dimension between the left column and the rest of the columns. Could you please take a minute and explain how the use of two replacement rules affects things and how you concluded to use 160 in the second replacement?  I haven't had time to look at PlotGrid, but it seems like a very useful function to add to my init.nb file.

Comment: mikemtnbikes, please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form `ImageSize -> a -> b` (still undocumented) makes `a` user units correspond to `b` printer's points. (See also: [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125))

Play with different values of `b` to have `plots` fit into the containing object without being clipped.

```
sizeinprinterpoints = 165;

plots = Table[Histogram[driftMatrix[i][[j]], binBoundaries, "PDF",
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 12}},
     Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
     FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, i /. {Max[iVals] -> Automatic, _ -> White}}, 
        {Automatic,  Automatic}}, 
     FrameTicks -> {Table[i /. {m[iVals] -> {{10, Style["0.5", Smaller]}}, _ -> None}, 
          {m, {Min, Max}}],
       {j /. {Max[rowVals] -> Range[0, 1, 0.25], _ -> None}, None}},
     AspectRatio -> 1/3,
     ImageSize -> 1 -> sizeinprinterpoints],
   {j, rowVals}, {i, iVals}];

xlabels = Text[Style[#, Medium]] & /@ (Join[8 iVals, {"Generation"}]);
ylabels = Text[Style[#, Medium]] & /@ (tVals);
    
Framed @ Labeled[Grid[Join[{xlabels}, Transpose[Join[Transpose[plots], {ylabels}]]]], 
  {"Population Size", "Bin Frequency", "Frequency of bw75 Allele"},
  {Top, Left, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True, ImageSize -> 12*72]
```

[image]

If you wish to specify the size in *inches* you can use `sizeinprinterpoints = 72 2.3` to get (almost) the same picture.

With `sizeinprinterpoints = 100;` we get

[image]