# Maintaining shape size while rotating in GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics, rotation, size

I've the following snippet, simplified from a more complex code:

```
Shape[x_] := Rectangle[
  {0, 0},
  {1, 1},
  RoundingRadius -> 0.1
  ]

exp1 = Table[
   {
    EdgeForm[Black],
    Hue[Sqrt[x]],
    Translate[
     Rotate[
      Shape[x],
      x
      ],
     {x*1.3, 0}
     ]
    },
   {x, 0, 10, 1}
   ];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Graphics /@ exp1, 10]]
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

How can I maintain the size of rectangles during the rotation? I'd like them to have all the same size.

Comment: why do you have `Shape[x_]` but `x` is not used any where in the function?

Comment: The `Partition` is discarding the last element of the `Table`. To retain that element use `GraphicsGrid[{Graphics /@ exp1}]` If the discard is intentional, additionally change the upper bound on the `Table` to `9`

Comment: @Nasser because Shape must represent a generic shape depending on the variable. In this particular example is not dependent from X because it was not the focus of the question, but I shoulr be able to use other shapes dependent on X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different sizes are created by the unnecessary "GraphicsGrid" that scales the different pictures. Without it:

```
SimplifyShape := Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> 0.1]
exp1 = Table[{EdgeForm[Black], Hue[Sqrt[x]], 
    Translate[Rotate[SimplifyShape, x], {x*1.5, 0}]}, {x, 0, 10, 1}];
exp1 // Graphics
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want an "regular array", that is a vector, of images the same size, use RotateImage:

```
exp1 = Table[
   ImageRotate[
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Hue[Sqrt[x]], SimplifyShape}], x, 
    Background -> Transparent], {x, 0, 10, 1}];
exp1
```

[image]

Comment: What if I need a rectangular array (that was the reason of `Partition`)?

Answer (score 8):

Translate a circle to the same location. Set the color of the circle to `White` and you will have what you are looking for. I am sure there are more formal solutions available.

```
Shape[x_] := Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> 0.1]

exp1 = Table[{
    EdgeForm[Black], Hue[Sqrt[x]], 
    Translate[Rotate[Shape[x], x], {x*1.3, 0}]
    , Black, Translate[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.7], {x*1.3, 0}]
    }, {x, 0, 10, 1}
   ];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Graphics /@ exp1, 10]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you could set the circle\`s opacity to `0`

Answer (score 7):

Specify `ImageSize` in each `Graphics` using the (*still undocumented*) syntax `ImageSize -> 1 -> size` (which makes `1` unit in *user units* correspond to `size` points in rendered image) :

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50] & /@ exp1, 10]]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 50] & /@ exp1, 10]]
```

[image]

Using with symbolic sizes:

```
Table[Labeled[GraphicsGrid[
      Partition[Graphics[#, ImageSize -> is] & /@ exp1, 10]], 
    Style[ImageSize -> is, 24], Top],
  {is, {5/3 -> Tiny, 3 -> Small, 6 -> Medium, 6 -> Automatic, 9.5 -> Large}}] //
 Column[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Use the 1st and 8th parts of `exp1` to compare the results of two ways of specifying image size. Note how the spec `ImageSize -> 1 -> size` modifies the *actual* image size so that an object with a length of `1` user unit rendered as `size` pixels long:

```
Row[Labeled[#, Column[{"ImageDimensions:", ImageDimensions @ #}, Center], Top] & @ 
   Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 200] & /@ exp1[[{1, 8}]]]
```

[image]

versus

```
Row[Labeled[#, Column[{"ImageDimensions:", ImageDimensions @ #}, Center], Top] & @
  Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ exp1[[{1, 8}]]]
```

[image]