# Graphics - nice variant of ImageSize (pixels per GraphicsUnitLength)

Tags: graphics, functions, function-construction, options

On my MMA, I apply the options

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 72/120}]
```

Then I can assure the output `Graphics` has the width specified in the ImageSize option.

For example the code

```
Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1], ImageSize -> 140]
```

[image]

creates 140-pixel wide `Graphics`.

To create graphics with two or three overlapping circles of the same size, I can do the following.

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
  Circle[{1, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 210]

Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
  Circle[{1, 0}, 1],
  Circle[{2, 0}, 1]
  }, ImageSize -> 280]
```

[image]

Notice that we **had to** calculated the value of `ImageSize` manually, to write the code.
The calculation was not that difficult, (140 * 1/2 *3 = 210, and 140 * 1/2 * 4 = 280)
so that it was possible to do with mental arithmetic and elementary school level knowledge of geometry.

But the example above was in fact very easy. It will be difficult to calculate `ImageSize` in a `Graphics` where figures of various sizes and shapes mixed.

In this sense, it would be very nice if we had an (imaginary) option `Pixels per Graphics Unit Length` like the one below. See the following imaginary screenshot :

[image]

Quetsion :
Is it possible to create `Graphics` of any size that I want, with the way explained above? I mean using **Pixels per Graphics Unit Length** concept.

Comment: does this give what you need: `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{1, 0}, 1], Circle[{2, 0}, 1]},  ImageSize -> 1 -> 70]`?

Comment: Wow! it works! Thank you very much! Simple and wonderful! You can write it as an answer If you want to be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the syntax `ImageSize -> 1 -> np` to make 1 unit in *user units* to be rendered as *np* printer points:

```
g1 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[10], Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 70, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 5];

g2 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{1, 0}, 1]},
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 70, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 5];

g3 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1/2], Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
      Circle[{1, 0}, 1], Circle[{2, 0}, 1]}, 
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 70, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 5];

Overlay[{g1, g2, g3}, Alignment -> {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: That syntax was new to me! Is it documented anywhere? (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB, afaik it  is still not documented. It has been used a number of times on this site; but I can't locate the relevant Q/As.

Comment: found a few: [Exporting image and scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125),  [Maintaining shape size while rotating in GraphicsGrid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263198/125)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Just for the record, np is in points.

Comment: thank you @ihojnicki - edited with the correction.