# How to match sizes of objects among several Graphics outputs?

Tags: graphics, scaling

I want disks of equal size to be depicted the same size on different outputs of `Graphics` and at the same time images should be nicely clipped without any unnecessary white area.

The first two images are nicely clipped but disks are not depicted the size.

The second two images depict the disks the same size but the second is not clipped nicely.

What I want can be seen in the fifth image (images sizes are of course different, but that does not matter for me).

```
o1 = Disk[#] & /@ {{0, 0}, {8, 2}};
o2 = Disk[#] & /@ {{0, 0}, {5, 0}};
Graphics[o1, Frame -> True]
Graphics[o2, Frame -> True]
b = RegionBounds[RegionUnion[Flatten@{o1, o2}]];
Graphics[o1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> b]
Graphics[o2, PlotRange -> b, Frame -> True]
Clear[o1, o2, b]
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
o1 = Disk[#] & /@ {{0, 0}, {8, 2}};
o2 = Disk[#] & /@ {{0, 0}, {5, 0}};
```

You can use the still-undocumented form `ImageSize -> a -> b` (which makes $a$ user units correspond to $b$ printer's points):

```
Graphics[o1, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 30]

Graphics[o2, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Where have you found such usage of `ImageSize`? I can not see it in documentation.

Comment: It is not in documentation. Don't remember where I first came across this usage. It has appeared in Q/As on this site a number of times: e.g., [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286125/125), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202701/125), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263198/125), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286133/125). Oldest post on this site using this form seems to be [this answer by rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43823/125).